# Problem with iterating through a list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

im trying to make a program to iterate through af list of lists containing 2 dictionaries with team informations of soccerteams. I want to get the match's winner from using for loops. My list looks like this:

```
matches = [[{'name': 'team bob', 'score': 3},
            {'name': 'team mia', 'score': 4}
           ],
           [{'name': 'team eva', 'score': 0},
            {'name': 'team storm', 'score': 4}
           ],
           [{'name': 'team storm', 'score': 0},
            {'name': 'team mia', 'score': 2}
           ],
           [{'name': 'team bob', 'score': 4},
            {'name': 'team storm', 'score': 4}
           ]]
```

and here ive tried on maked some for loops but i cant figure out why i cant iterate correctly through them to check each match for the winner. This is what ive come up with

```
def scoredMost(matches):
    for match in matches:
        for team in match:
            print(team)



scoredMost(matches)
```

Comment: change to : `print(team['name'])`

Answer (score 2):

This would print the winner of each match, not sure if this is all that you wanted

```
def scoredMost(matches):

    # THIS JUST PRINTS THE WINNER
    for match in matches:
        print("Winner of match is ", end='')
        if match[0]['score'] > match[1]['score']:
            print(f"{match[0]['name']} with a score of {match[0]['score']}")
        elif match[0]['score'] < match[1]['score']:
            print(f"{match[1]['name']} with a score of {match[1]['score']}")
        else:
            print("Tie")
```

Answer (score 1):

The may give you an idea of how you can navigate these lists and dictionaries:

```
matches = [[{'name': 'team bob', 'score': 3},
            {'name': 'team mia', 'score': 4}
           ],
           [{'name': 'team eva', 'score': 0},
            {'name': 'team storm', 'score': 4}
           ],
           [{'name': 'team storm', 'score': 0},
            {'name': 'team mia', 'score': 2}
           ],
           [{'name': 'team bob', 'score': 4},
            {'name': 'team storm', 'score': 4}
           ]]
for teamA, teamB in matches:
    if teamA['score'] == teamB['score']:
        print(f'Match tied between {teamA["name"]} and {teamB["name"]}')
    elif teamA['score'] > teamB['score']:
        print(f'{teamA["name"]} beat {teamB["name"]}')
    else:
        print(f'{teamB["name"]} beat {teamA["name"]}')
```

**Output:**

```
team mia beat team bob
team storm beat team eva
team mia beat team storm
Match tied between team bob and team storm
```